# How to index for a self join

Tags: sql, indexing, sas

I'm using SAS University Edition to analyze the following table (actually has 2.5M rows in it)

```
p_id c_id startyear endyear
0001 3201      2008    2013
0001 2131      2013    2015
0013 3201      2006    2010
```

where p_id is person_id and c_id is companyid.

I want to get number of colleagues (number of persons that worked during an overlapping span at the same companies) in a certain year, so I created a table with the distinct p_ids and do the following query:

```
PROC SQL;

UPDATE no_colleagues AS t1
SET c2007 = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.p_id) - 1
    FROM table AS t2
    INNER JOIN table AS t3
    ON  t3.p_id = t1.p_id
    AND t3.c_id = t2.c_id
    AND t3.startyear <= t2.endyear   % checks overlapping criteria
    AND t3.endyear >= t2.startyear   % checks overlapping criteria
    AND t3.startyear <= 2007         % limits number of returns
    AND t2.startyear <= 2007         % limits number of returns
);
```

A single lookup on an indexed query (p_id, c_id, startyear, endyear) takes 0.04 seconds. The query above takes about 1.8 seconds for a single update, and does not use any indexes.

So my question is:

How to improve the query, and/or how to use indices to make sure the self join can use the indices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please attache `EXPLAIN` plan.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data, I'd do something like this, but maybe you need to tweak the code to fit your needs.

First, create a table with p_id, c_id, year.
So your first guy working at the company 3201 will have 6 observations in this table, one for each worked year.

```
data have_count;
    set have;

do i=startyear to endyear;
    worked_in = i;
    output;
end;

drop i startyear endyear;
run;
```

Now you just count and agreggate:

```
proc sql;
select
    worked_in as year
    ,c_id
    ,count(distinct p_id) as no_colleagues
from have_count
group by 1,2;
quit;
```

Result:

```
year c_id no_colleagues 
2006 3201 1 
2007 3201 1 
2008 3201 2 
2009 3201 2 
2010 3201 2 
2011 3201 1 
2012 3201 1 
2013 2131 1 
2013 3201 1 
2014 2131 1 
2015 2131 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient method:

1) Create a long format table for the results rather than wide format.  This will be both easier to populate and easier to work with later.

```
create table colleagues_by_year (
    p_id int,
    year int,
    colleagues int
);
```

Now this can be populated with a single `insert` statement.  The only trick is getting the full list of years you want in the final table.  There are a few options, but since I'm not too familiar with SAS SQL I'm going to go with a very simple one: a lookup table of years, to which you can join.

```
create table years (
   year int
);

insert into years 
   values (2007),(2008),...
```

(A more sophisticated approach would be a recursive query that found the range of all years in the input data).

Now the final insert:

```
insert into colleagues_by_year
    select p_id,
           year,
           count(*)
       from colleagues
       join years on
          years.year between colleagues.startyear and colleagues.endyear
       group by p_id,year
```

This won't have any rows where the number of colleagues for the year would be 0.  If you wanted that you could make years be a left join and only count the rows where years.year is not null.